# How can orientdb create a index at the same time can accept written

Tags: orientdb

I'm sorry I ask agin. If I can't solve, orientdb can't put into production.

My orientdb server version is 2.1.11, woking in distribute mode.

I find when I create a index, all the node can't be written, request clients occurred "Quorum x not reached for request".

How can orientdb create a index at the same time can accept written, rather than lock the cluster (all nodes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write while you are creating the index because the nodes are in synchronization.

**UPDATE**

Currently when nodes are in synchronization is done the entire backup of the database, and so this takes away the time.
I see the documentation about 2.2 beta ( http://orientdb.com/orientdb-labs/ )  and I found

*Operations*

Our users have been asking for incremental backup, so we delivered. Now it’s ready to be tested! That’s not the only addition to version 2.2, as the new OrientDB Studio now replaces the workbench, adding a new architecture and new modules.

*Performance*

We’ve done multiple optimizations to the core engine and, in many cases, performance increased tenfold. Our distributed capabilities are also constantly improving and we’ve introduced fast-resync of nodes. This release supports the new configurable Graph Consistency to speed-up change operations against graphs

Comment: thank you for answer. But is there no solution? This scenario is common, it is impossible for me to stop the client. If so, I can't use orientdb in product environment.